# Pasar a través de un campo oculto un array

Tags: php, array

En un campo oculto tengo esto:

```
 input type="text" name="campoOculto" value="<?php print serialize($arrayOculto)?>">
```

El cual, cuando se pulse el botón de enviar, quiero poder leer el contenido de éste, y el problema que tengo es al leerlo (o eso creo).

Pongo esto:

```
$arrayOculto=unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['campoOculto']));
```

Al ejecutar la aplicación me sale el siguiente error:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 123 bytes.

**Mi codigo:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

               $arrayOculto=unserialize(stripslashes($_POST['campoOculto']));
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $telefonos = $_POST['telefono'];

               if(!isset($_POST['campoOculto']) && $_POST['campoOculto']=="" ) 
                  {
                    $pruebaArray=$arrayOculto;
                    $pruebaArray[$nombre]=$telefonos; 

                     $arrayOculto=$pruebaArray;

                  }  
                 else
                     {
                     $pruebaArray[$nombre]=$telefonos; 

                     $arrayOculto=$pruebaArray;

                     }

            }

      ?>
        <form name="input" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" /><br />
            Telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="campoOculto" value="<?php print serialize($arrayOculto)?>">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" /><br />



        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Editado**: he modificado esto porque tengo que hacer una array asociativo, tengo que ir guardando una agenda el nombre y el telefono ("pedro" => "5478..") para luego mostrarlo por pantalla. Para ello tengo que usar un campo oculto. Al sacarlo por pantalla me sale asi:

NOMBRE: 0 TELEFONO: Array( [0] => Array( [Alvaro] => 4545) [asdasd] => 4545)NOMBRE: Pedro TELEFONO: 2

```
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

          // $arrayOculto=$_POST['campoOculto'];
          // print_r($arrayOculto);

           // print_r($arrayOculto);
            $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
            $telefonos = $_POST['telefono'];

           if($_POST['bandera']!="" ) {
               $bandera=1;
                $arrayOculto=$_POST['campoOculto'];
                //print_r($arrayOculto);
                print '<br/>';
                //foreach ($arrayOculto as $nom => $tel)
                  //  {
                  //  print "Nombre2: ".$nom." Telefono2: ". $tel; 
                   // }
                $pruebaArray=$arrayOculto; 

                $pruebaArray[$nombre]=$telefonos; 
               //print_r($pruebaArray);

                 // print_r($arrayOculto."<br/>");
                 $arrayOculto=$pruebaArray;
                    foreach ($pruebaArray as $nom => $tel)
                    {
                    print "NOMBRE: ".$nom." TELEFONO: ". $tel; 
                    }
                  //print_r($arrayOculto);
               //      foreach ($arrayOculto as $nombre => $telefono )
              //  {
               //     print "Nombre2: ".$nombre." Telefono2: ". $telefono;
                //}
                // print_r("Si no esta vacio " . print_r($arrayOculto));

        }  
             else
                 {
                 //$arrayOculto=$_POST['campoOculto'];
                 $bandera=$_POST['bandera'];
                 $bandera=1;

                $arrayOculto[$nombre]=$telefonos; 
                print_r($arrayOculto);
                  // print_r($arrayOculto);
              //     foreach ($pruebaArray as $nombre => $telefono )
                //{
                 //   print "Nombre2: ".$nombre." Telefono2: ". $telefono;
                 //}
                 //$arrayOculto[]=$pruebaArray;
                // print_r($arrayOculto);
                 }


        }

  ?>
    <form name="input" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
        Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre" /><br />
        Telefono: <input type="text" name="telefono" /><br />
        <input type="text" name="bandera" value="<?php
        if(!empty($bandera)) {
echo $bandera;
```

} ?>">
            ">

```
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" /><br />



    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Pero a ver, ¿en tu `input` oculto hay **realmente** información apta para ser unserializada? ¿Si pones en tu `input` un valor como este por ejemplo: `O:1:"a":1:{s:5:"valor";s:3:"100";}`, te sigue ocurriendo lo mismo? ¿Sabes para qué se debe usar [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unserialize.php)?

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar un valor oculto podrías usar el `input` de tipo `hidden`, así no se verá en tu formulario.

En tu atributo `name` debes declarar que vas a recibir un `array`, algo como `name="campoOculto[]"`

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
$arrayOculto = array("a","b","c");

foreach($arrayOculto as $value)
{
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="campoOculto[]" value="'. $value. '">';
}
```

De esta manera obtendrás `$_POST['campoOculto']` como un `array`.

```
print_r($_POST['campoOculto']);
```

*Resultado:* `Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )`

Código fuente: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547209/passing-array-using-html-form-hidden-element)

**Segundo ejemplo:**

Como no veo como creas tu `array`, pongo un posible ejemplo.

```
<form method="post">
    <?php
        //Datos a asociar.
        $nom = 'Daniel';
        $tel = '5555555';

        //Creas tu array.
        $arrayOculto = [ 'nombre' => $nom, 'telefono' => $tel ];

        //Añadimos los valores del array a nuestro input.
        foreach($arrayOculto as $value)
        {
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="campoOculto[]" value="'. $value. '">';
        }

    ?>  
    <input type="submit" value="ok" />

</form>
```

Ahora si deseas mostrar dichos datos podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php 

    if (isset($_POST)) {  

        //Nuestros datos ocultos
        $data = $_POST['campoOculto'];

        //print_r($data);
        //Resultado: Array ( [0] => Daniel [1] => 5555555 ) 

        //Mostrar en pantalla.
        echo "Nombre: " . $data[0] ."<br>";
        echo "Telefono:" . $data[1];
    }           
?>
```

Resultado:

```
Nombre: Daniel
Telefono:5555555
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero lo que busco es un array asociativo para guardar una agenda con nombre y telefono. (acabo de editar la pregunta)

Comment: Hola @Alvaro, te he dejado un segundo ejemplo, tampoco entendí bien su modificación, he puesto un ejemplo como crear un array y posterior mostrar dichos datos en pantalla, espero verte ayuda, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

`serialize()` y `unserialize()` NO deberían ser usados con esta finalidad, proporcionar datos no fiables provenientes de un usuario a `unserialize()` puede ser muy peligroso.

Para solventar este problema se debe utilizar un formato de intercambio de datos seguro y estándar, como JSON (a través de `json_decode()` y `json_encode()` )

Por ejemplo:

```
<input 
    type="hidden"
    name="campoOculto" 
    value='<?= json_encode($arrayOculto, JSON_HEX_APOS); ?>'
>
```

Y en PHP

```
$arrayOculto = json_decode($_POST['campoOculto'], true);
```

Otra opción  podría ser almacenar el Array en una variable de session.